# Is it bad practice to instantiate an object as an argument inside a method/function call?

Tags: php, oop

Is it bad practice to instantiate an object as an argument? For example, is it bad practice to do this?

```
myFunction(new Foo);
```

Or should you *always* do it this way:

```
$foo = new Foo;
myFunction($foo);
```

**My specific Scenario..**

I ask because I'm in a situation where I need to pass many new objects into a method to "register" a bunch of plugins. It's something along the lines of this:

```
$imagePlugin = new ImagePlugin;
$videoPlugin = new VideoPlugin;
$audioPlugin = new AudioPlugin;

$myLibrary->registerPlugins(array(
        $imagePlugin,
        $videoPlugin,
        $audioPlugin
    ));
```

I'm wondering if its okay, according to best practices, to shorten it to the code below:

```
$myLibrary->registerPlugins(array(
        new ImagePlugin,
        new VideoPlugin,
        new AudioPlugin
    ));
```

Comment: This is just coding style, it makes no difference to the computer. It's no different from whether you do `func($a+$b)` or `$sum=$a+$b; func($sum)`

Comment: Totally, but there are lots of "best practices" that apply merely to coding style.

Comment: that'd depend on if you need to use the Foo object elsewhere in your method. Unless whatever you're doing inside myFunction somehow returns Foo, it'll be lost to you once myFunction returns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not need them outside the function call, I would say you're doing right in instantiating them directly as arguments.